# Is there a $G_\delta$ set with Positive Measure and Empty Interior?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

It is like in the title. $G_\delta\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with Lebesgue measure.

Thanks for any help

Comment: It could even be a closed set in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes: any [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) in $\Bbb R$ is an example, since all closed sets in $\Bbb R$ are $G_\delta$’s.

Comment: @Tomás: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Aw, that one’s boring! :-) +1

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

For $n\in\mathbb N$ let $F_n = \{x\in(0,1)|\;\exists m\in\mathbb Z:x=\frac{m}{n}\}$ and $U_n=(0,1)\setminus F_n$. The sets $U_n$ are open and have measure $1$, but the intersection $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n$ is simply the set of all irrational numbers in $(0,1)$. It is thus a $G_\delta$ set with measure $1$ and empty interior.