# Support of measurable function regular?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain.
We take a measurable function $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ and define its support as $$\mathrm{supp}(f) = \{x \in \Omega : f(x) \ne 0\}.$$
If we are thinking of equivalence classes of functions, the support is defined only up to a set of measure zero.
Can we modify $f$ on a set of measure zero, such that the support is regular in the sense of "it equals the closure of its interior"?

It looks reasonable, but I couldn't find an idea to prove it.

Comment: BTW, functions don't need to enter into it. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is open and hence Borel, if $f$ is measurable $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is (Lebesgue) measurable. Conversely you have that if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable set, the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A$ is measurable and has support precisely $A$. So your question is really about measurable sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Since there exists [closed sets with positive measure and empty interior](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221790/1543).

Take any [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) $C$. Let $A$ be any non-empty open set. Since $C$ is closed, we have that $A\setminus C$ is open and non-empty. So $A\setminus C$ contains an interval and has positive measure.

Hence we see that we cannot enlarge $C$ by any measure zero set to get something with nonempty interior.

On the other hand, since $C$ has empty interior, we cannot remove from $C$ any measure zero set to get something with nonempty interior.

Appropriately combining the above two facts yields that your desired modification is not possible for the function $f = \mathbf{1}_C$.

Comment: Aw, that's too simple ;) I already thought about these not-so-nice sets, but didn't find the right conclusion.